# C# Special character in Json read from file, specially Quote " throws exception when deserializing

Tags: c#, json, winforms, json.net

I have to read json from a downloaded files which has the following Json

```
    {
  "configuration": {
    "aboutDisplayServerName": false,
    "aboutText": "This application/solution allows public safety personnel to relay important emergency  "information" to your computer. Currently we are testing and  along with along with one double quote " and two single quotes ''. Let's see.",
    "applicationName": "My Desktop",
    "loggingLevel": "INFO",
    "logonScreenAlertsEnabled": true,
    "maxAlertsInHistory": 5,
    "minSecondsBeforeClosingAlert": 1,
    "name": "Gary",
    "panicButtonCooldownMillis": 0,
    "TimeOutMillis": 10000,
    "requestTimeoutMillis": 30000,
    "showExit": true,
    "showInSystemTrayMode": "Always",
    "showRecentMessages": true,
    "showViewLogs": true,
  },
  
}
```

I am trying to deserizle the json using following function

```
public static void LoadJson()
    {
        Configuration Configuration = new Configuration();

        
        string mConfigFileLoc = @"C:\ProgramData\My Desktop\Configuration.json";
        
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(mConfigFileLoc))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();

            var objonfiguration = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            JObject jObject = ((JObject)objConfiguration);
            Configuration = jObject.ToObject<Configuration>();
        }
    }
```

I am getting the error

```
After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: i. Path 'configuration.aboutText', line 1, position 157.
```

Even the follwoing Json with a single double quote " is problematic

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "aboutDisplayServerName": false,
    "aboutText": "This application allows public safety personnel to relay important emergency alert "information to your computer.",
    "applicationName": "My Desktop",
    "loggingLevel": "INFO",
    "logonScreenAlertsEnabled": true,
    "maxAlertsInHistory": 5,
    "minSecondsBeforeClosingAlert": 1,
    "name": "Gary",
    "panicButtonCooldownMillis": 0,
    "TimeOutMillis": 10000,
    "requestTimeoutMillis": 30000,
    "showExit": true,
    "showInSystemTrayMode": "Always",
    "showRecentMessages": true,
    "showViewLogs": true,
  },
  
}
```

and one more thing, this json is being downloaded from a site and about text is added by the user
[image]

The question is how can I handle special character like Quote " within a node/value.

Can any one help me in this regard? Thanks.

Ironically, the site is formatting the Json properly with escape sequences. When I try to save it to a local file and then retrieve it, thats where the proper escape sequences get vanished.

Comment: That JSON is not valid JSON - so as far as we're concerned, everything's running as-expected. If you're wanting your program to be able to read invalid JSON, then that's another question entirely - and you need to decide how to handle each different kind of invalid input (e.g. malformed strings, especially in this case).

Comment: ...May I ask why your Desktop folder is located under `ProgramData`? That directory is meant for systemwide application files and data, not for per-user or personal files...

Comment: Double-quotes in JSON string literals must be escaped, e.g.: `"important emergency  \"information\" to your computer"`.

Comment: Your JSON is malformed.  Upload it to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and you will see many errors.  Specifically a double-quote character inside a string literal **must** be escaped as \" according to https://json.org/.  But as mentioned by @500-InternalServerError the value of `"aboutText"` contains unescaped double quotes.  The site from which you downloaded the JSON will need to fix its code to serialize JSON correctly.

Comment: "Ironically, the site is formatting the Json properly with escape sequences" - which site? It's very unclear what you're trying to say.